# Attempt to index nil with ‘WaitForChild’?

Tags: lua, roblox

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDaYK.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUMhB.png)

I am in roblox studio and i got this when i was making an animation for my game it includes a humanoid i am attempting to animate. There are two animations the first one works but the other doesn't i get this error. when i place the humanoid down the animation  does not start however the first one does as intended but the other one should start whenever the humanoid attacks. Please help i will appreciate anything

(code)

`local function setAnimation(object, animName)`

`local humanoid = object:WaitForChild("Humanoid")`

`local animationsFolder = object:WaitForChild("Animations")`

(error)

Attempt to index nil with ‘WaitForChild'

Comment: Heyo, when sharing your code and errors, please copy and paste the text into a formatted code block. When you post pictures of your code, it makes it very difficult for us to use your code and help you. Could you please edit your question and share your code in text form?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)" and their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

`object` is a nil value. Hence you may not index it. Find out why it is nil and fix that. So you need to go to your `setAnimation` call and ensure that the first argument is actually an Instance, not a nil value. So you either call `setAnimation()` without any arguments or you provide some uninitialized variable as the first argument.

Comment: would i replace `object:WaitForChild("Humanoid")` with `setAnimation()`?

Comment: no you would do a Lua beginnerst tutorial  and both read Programming in Lua and the Lua reference manual befor you continue with Roblox.  replacing that with `setAnimation()` would cause an infinite recursion resulting in a stack overflow. setAnimation would just call itself over and over. If you don't know how to fix this you are not ready to work with Roblox. Learn a few basics first. you need to provide an Instance to `setAnimation` for this to work.

Comment: the last sentence of my answer doesn't say what you shoud do, it tells you the two possible reasons for object to be nil. if you want object to be an Instance that has the WaitForChild method you need to provide an Instance value to the function call. not nil